# Establish the inequality

Tags: number-theory, induction

Establish the inequality $2^n < \binom{2n}{n} < 2^{2n}$, for $n > 1$.

Hint: Put $x = 2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots(2n)$ ; $y = 1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n - 1)$ and $z = 1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots n$ , then show that $x > y > z $ and subsequently $x^2 > xy > xz$.

Now I am not able to understand that how can I equate $x^2 > xy > yz $ with $ 2^n < \binom{2n}{n} < 2^{2n}$, any sort of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $x= 2^{n} \cdot n!$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x=2^nn!$:

$$\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}=\frac{xy}{x^22^{-2n}}<2^{2n},$$

since $x^2>xy$. Also,

$$\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{xy}{(x2^{-n})z}=2^n\frac{xy}{xz}>2^n,$$

since $xy>xz$.